# EF6 lazy loading doesn't work while eager loading works fine

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I updated my app from EF4.1 to EF6 and now I've got lazy loading issue. I used EF6.x DbContext Generator to generate new DbContext. All of the advices from this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx) are also applied.

- My classes are public
- Not sealed, not abstract
- Have a public constructor
- Don't implement neither `IEntityWithChangeTracker` nor `IEntityWithRelationships`
- Both `ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` are set to true
- Navigation properties are virtual

What also looks wierd to me is that if I explicitly include navigation property with `Include("...")` it gets loaded.

Simplified version of my POCOs and DbContext:

```
public partial class Ideation
{
    public Ideation()
    {

    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ChallengeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Challenge Challenge { get; set; }
}

public partial class Challenge
{
    public Challenge()
    {
        this.Ideations = new HashSet<Ideation>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ideation> Ideations { get; set; }
}

public partial class BoxEntities : DbContext
{
    public TIBoxEntities()
        : base("name=BoxEntities")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Ideation> Ideations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
```

Also I tried to set `ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` explicitly without no luck. The entity isn't loaded as a dynamic proxy as this debug session screenshot shows:

[image: Debug]

What else am I missing?

Comment: Could you post a (simplified) copy of your DbContext class?

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything wrong. How are you configuring your ObjectContext? Also, are you using model first approach?

Comment: @ken2k, DbContext instances creted via Ninject injection and there is no extra configuration involved. Yes, it's model first approach.

Comment: `LazyLoadingEnabled` should be `false` by default. Did you modified this value on the EDMX properties?

Comment: @ken2k, no but when I debug constructor of DbContext I see that it's already set to true and if I set it explicitly then nothing is changed.

Comment: Do you see dynamically created proxy entity types when adding a breakpoint after having retrieved an entity from your context (i.e. types containing an hexadecimal part in their type name)?

Comment: @ken2k, no just the regular type name. http://screencast.com/t/ewtCpXwpW

Comment: Could you try forcing both ProxyCreationEnabled and LazyLoadingEnabled to be true against the ObjectContext _just_ before executing a query, and see if you still don't have a proxy entity?

Comment: @ken2k None of those helped. http://screencast.com/t/AatfBT2UNVOW

Comment: Sorry, I'm really out of idea now :( Your last screenshot shows pretty straightforward code, no context disposed...etc. I upvoted your question, hopefully someone will find out what's going wrong. Really, everything looks fine to me, I can't tell why proxy are not created.

Comment: I would suggest adding your last screenshot directly in the question, it adds a lot of information about how you access to the context.

Comment: @ken2k, thank you for your support. Looks like it's time to debug the EF code itself.

Comment: I've added the debug image directly to the question. That's indeed an interesting problem. I can't see either what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A situation where this could happen is that the entity you are trying to load with `Find` is already attached to the context as a non-proxy object. For example:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var ideation = new Ideation { Id = 1 }; // this is NOT a proxy
    context.Ideations.Attach(ideation);

    // other stuff maybe ...

    var anotherIdeation = context.Ideations.Find(1);
}
```

`anotherIdeation` will be the non-proxy that is already attached and it is not capable of lazy loading. It even wouldn't help to run a DB query with `var anotherIdeation = context.Ideations.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);` because the default merge option for queries is `AppendOnly`, i.e. the new entity would only be added if there isn't already an attached entity with that key. So, `anotherIdeation` would still be a non-proxy.

You can check if the entity is already attached by using `Local` before you call `Find` in your `GetById` method:

```
bool isIdeationAttached = context.Ideations.Local.Any(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: that was the actual case. Non-proxy entities were attached to the `DbContext`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Per @ken2k's comment, the default for new models starting with EF 4 was to enable lazy loading by default. With EF 1, it was not allowed. If you migrated your model from 1 to 4, it is kept off by default. You would need to modify the context to turn that on.

That being said, you indicate through debugging that it is true. In that case, check your usage scenarios. Is it possible your context has been disposed prior to fetching the child objects. Typically we see this when data binding to the LINQ query where the context is configured in a Using block and the actual iteration doesn't happen until after the using block's scope has passed.

Comment: I tried to set LazyLoadingEnabled explicitly without no luck. Also the context lifetime is per request so it isn't disposed yet at a time of child objects fetch.